# Adding a sign to number

Tags: javascript, math

I need to determine if the value should incremented or decremented based on a variable (debit / credit) and return a signed number.

Since this is a critical part of the program, I'd just like to double check if this is indeed a correct / best way to go about it:

```
var direction = 'debit';
var amount = 99.99
var signed = Number((direction === 'debit' ? '-' : '') + Math.abs(amount))
console.log(signed) // -99.99

var direction = 'credit';
var amount = 99.99
var signed = Number((direction === 'debit' ? '-' : '') + Math.abs(amount))
console.log(signed) // 99.99
```

Comment: is amount always positive? why not multiply with sign?

Comment: I assume you can not be sure, that the entered value for amount already has a sign or not, otherwise you would not need this at all. But why do you want to have a string in the end? Why not `Math.abs(amount) * (direction  === 'debit' ? 1 : -1)` .

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, its always 'unsigned', so never `-99.99'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For always positive numbers, you could multiply with a wanted sign.

```js
var direction = 'debit';
var amount = 99.99
var signed = (direction === 'debit' ? -1 : 1) * amount
console.log(signed) // -99.99

direction = 'credit';
amount = 99.99
signed = (direction === 'debit' ? -1 : 1) * amount
console.log(signed) // 99.99
```